# Connect multiple Android/iPhone Devices to MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, android, iphone, ad-hoc-network

my plan is to control my MacBook via OSC from different smartphones (android/iphone). When I do that in my personal network, everything works fine. But I wonder if it's also possible to create a WiFi hotspot with my MacBook, that the devices can connect to it. I tried this with the in MacOS X (10.10) built in 'share internet connection' feature, but this only works when I got an attached ethernet cable with internet access. (I don't need internet)
The other thing what I have tried is to create an adhoc network, but this works only with my iphone and not with the android device.
So does someone know a tool or a possibilty that my mac can act like a wifi hotspot to which my devices can connect?

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options

A. Get a cheap ($20) Wi-Fi router.

B. Jailbreak your iPhone and install MiWi

C. Create an Ad-Hoc network with your mac.